# How to make REST api which compiles C and C++ code using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to make a REST api with nodejs which compiles the c and c++ code and send back the result in response using nodejs,like codechef

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 2):

First of all this is not how `codechef` or any other platform works. They don't send the executable, they compile, run and then send the results. Assuming something very simple with no security considerations.

### Upload the file

First you need to place file on your drive to be found by `gcc` compiler. This is more about uploading file using express so i won't be covering that part over here.

### Invoke compiler

Assuming that the file is placed at `/code/file.cc` your nodejs code to compile should be

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;
// Remeber change cmd to put a unique output exe name
// For now assuming output at /code/a.out
var cmd=(gcc,['/code/file.cc'];
child = exec(cmd,
   function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      if (error !== null) {
        console.log("Error while compiling your file");
      }else{
         console.log("File compiled");
      }
   });
```

### Run the file

Now assuming the last step went through and you have the compiled binary, time, you can either as pointed in your question send them to client using express or if you want to run the file and check the output like `codechef`,

use `child_process` again to run the file. You would get the output of file from `stdout`.

### Queue

Now the whole process of compiling the file and running the same might take some time, i might advise using `zmq` or `redis` queue to run the job in background.

### Security considerations

Currently you are running the executable in bare metal server which is bad and opens you up to security exploits. It might be advisable that you run the executable in some `virtual environment`. This is a long topic, but to get you started, you can have a look at `Qemu` or `Docker` depending on your needs.